# How to make Javascript Word Counter work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, word-count

I'm new to JavaScript. I set up a word counter on a form using JavaScript. It works great in all browsers except - you guessed it - IE. In both IE9 and IE11 the counter is unreliable, and the whole field can 'freeze up' and not allow you to click in it and edit anything.

Why does it break in IE? And if it can't be fixed in a simple way, is there a way to conditionally use the script only if the browser is not IE?

Here's a demo of the form: http://nzensandbox.wpmakeover.com/

And the code:

```
$("#field_advstatement").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var words = $.trim(this.value).length ? this.value.match(/\S+/g).length : 0;
    if (words <= 50) {
        $('#display_count2').text(words);
        $('#word_left2').text(50-words)
    }else{
        if (e.which !== 8) e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error being thrown on the console in IE?

Comment: It'd be smart for you to create a small test case on http://jsfiddle.net/ where we can replicate the issue

Comment: btw, the field Company Statement (50 words) from above link is not working in Chrome as well.. try entering "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee". it always gives Total word count: 1 words. Words left: 49

Comment: Why wouldn't "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" count as a single word?

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/trishacupra/g2uthuxn/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script>
      function countChar(val) {
        var len = val.value.length;
        if (len >= 50) {
          val.value = val.value.substring(0, 50);
        } else {
          $('#charNum').text(50 - len);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <textarea id="field" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
    <div id="charNum"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript **split** method does the trick.
Try the updated fiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2uthuxn/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var countMyWords = function(obj){
            var $input = $(obj);
            var words = $input.val().trim().split(' ');

            $('#display_count2').text(words.length);
            $('#word_left2').text(50 - words.length);


        }
        $('#field_advstatement').on({
            keyup

 : function(event){
                    if(event.which == 8){
                        countMyWords(this);
                return true;
            }
           var len = $(this).val().length;
            if (len >= 50) {
                event.preventDefault();

            }

           countMyWords(this);

        },
        keydown: function(event){
            if(event.which == 8){
              countMyWords(this);
                return true;
            }

            var len = $(this).val().length;
            if (len >= 50) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
           countMyWords(this);
        }
    });
    });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm too dense to know how to apply this to my code - http://jsfiddle.net/trishacupra/g2uthuxn/

It seems to be counting characters rather than words, and I'm not sure how to do the countdown as well as the count-up.